# How to properly handle wrong urlsafe key provided?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception, app-engine-ndb

I use the following code to get entity based on urlsafe `key` given:

```
q_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=key)
q = q_key.get()
return q
```

But in case there is no such entity with given urlsafe key, it return 
`ProtocolBufferDecodeError: Unable to merge from string` on the first line, when I would expect `q` to be equal to `None`. Is there any other correct way to handle such case except of catching `ProtocolBufferDecodeError` exception?

Comment: catching `ProtocolBufferDecodeError` and returning None seems fine for me.

Comment: @DanCornilescu, this question has been asked before in 2015 (when my question as of 2013), ooook :)

Answer (score 7):

[There is an open bug report for it here](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=143)

The workaround is...

```
from google.net.proto.ProtocolBuffer import ProtocolBufferDecodeError
try:
   q_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=key)
   q = q_key.get()
except ProtocolBufferDecodeError:    
   q = None
return q
```

I'm a little puzzled as to why this isn't a more common complaint yet. Doesn't anyone test their urls with invalid keys?

Comment: Still nothing for this? I was writing tests today and hit this. In my case previous App Engine projects didn't use a urlsafe key, so that's why I never hit it previously. Still it's kind of odd that there's not a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
try:
    q_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=key)
    q = q_key.get()
except ProtocolBufferDecodeError:    
    q = None
return q
```